# Chrome and Safari close tab event not firing in vue app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome, safari, tabs

I am building a vue web app where a socket event gets fired if the user closes the tab. The feature works fine in Firefox, but works ~50% of the time in Chrome and Safari. Ive seen the code I use in many examples so I'm at a loss as to why it doesn't work consistently in Chrome and Safari for me. Would appreciate any insights or further ways to debug. Here is my code:

```
created() {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", this.leave);
},
methods: {
   leave() {
      this.socket.emit("leave-channel");
    }
},
beforeDestroy() {
    this.leave();
    window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", this.leave);
}
```

Comment: Ok. What isn't working here? Does the event not get emitted on closing the tab? Or in `beforeDestroy`?

Comment: Apologies for not making it clearer; the part that isn't working is the `beforeunload` event is only getting triggered/heard/calling `leave` about 50% of the time. and I confirmed this because `leave` emits an event to my server and logs out a message. so i can tell when `beforeunload` is triggered because I see the message in my logs